# Relationship between R and a submodule of a R-module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Consider a commutative ring with unity, call it $\mathbf{R}$. Suppose that $\mathbf{S}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbf{R}$-module and has a submodule $\mathbf{T}$. Then I was wondering if it holds that $\mathbf{R} \subseteq \mathbf{T}$ or even $\mathbf{T} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$. Then I considered the commutative ring $\mathbb{Z}$ with the ideal $2\mathbb{Z}$. And I set

$\mathbf{S}=\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$

$\mathbf{T}=2\mathbb{Z}(\sqrt{2})$

Then clearly neither of  $\mathbf{R} \subseteq \mathbf{T}$ or $\mathbf{T} \subseteq \mathbf{R}$ holds. Is this a valid counterexample; i.e., is $\mathbf{T}$ valid submodule (I guess so since multiplying $a+b\sqrt{2}$ in $\mathbf{S}$ and $2c+2d\sqrt{2}$ gives always a number in $\mathbf{T}$, where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{Z}$)

Comment: it doesn't even make sense to wonder if $R\subseteq T$ or $T\subseteq R$ because $R$ and $S$ are disjoint sets (a priori). It might happen that you have an injection of $R$-modules $R\to T$, for example if $R=\mathbb Z$, $S=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3}]$ and $T=\mathbb Z[\sqrt{2}]$ you have an obvious injection $R\to T$. Of course it might also happen that you have an injection of $R$-modules $T\to R$, but in general wondering if $R\subseteq T$ is a nonsense question.

Comment: But $\mathbf{R} \subseteq \mathbf{S}$ since $\mathbf{S}$ is finitely generated by $\mathbf{R}$? So it makes sense to check whether subsets of $\mathbf{S}$ are in $\mathbf{R}$ or $\mathbf{R}$ is included in them although neither of it might hold.

Comment: This is false. For example, $\mathbb{F}_2 = \{0,1\}$ is a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, but $\mathbb{Z} \not\subset \mathbb{F}_2$.

Comment: Ok. What generators has this $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: I should say that I am talking about Noether modules.

Comment: @Ferra: I'm sorry, I can't agree with this sentiment. From this perspective it's equally nonsensical to ask whether $F\subseteq V$ where $V$ is a vector space over $F$. The answer is "no" strictly speaking. But the *question* is useful anyway because what is true is that there is an injective homomorphism of vector spaces $F\to V$, and $\subseteq$ often means something similar, e.g. when we write $\mathbb R\subseteq\mathbb C$. The fact that this need *not* happen with modules in general is (I think) a rather worthwhile fact, and makes me inclined to think the question is worthwhile as well.

Comment: @EricStucky I just meant that the question is nonsensical in the way it was stated. I agree that morally it makes sense to wonder if you have some injection $F\to V$, but then you have to ask it this way. When you have two sets that are a priori unrelated it makes no sense to me to wonder if one is a subset of the other. Also, in your example you don't even have a canonical homomorphism $F\to V$, which makes the question even more subtle in some sense. Then I know that when one is informally talking one can write $A\subseteq B$ to mean that there is an injection, but I still don't like it.

Comment: This is ofcourse what I meant by "$\subseteq$". I understand that $\mathbb{F}_2$ is a submodule in the $\mathbf{Z}$-module $\mathbf{Z}$ since it is an ideal in $\mathbf{Z}$. But $\mathbb{F}_2$ as a finitely generated module over $\mathbf{Z}$ how can that hold? In the basis must be 1 so we must have an injective map from $\mathbf{Z}$ to the finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module?

Comment: I think you're a bit confused with the definitions. $\mathbb F_2$ isn't in any way an ideal of $\mathbb Z$, it is a quotient of $\mathbb Z$. And yes, it is a f.g. $\mathbb Z$-module and it is generated over $\mathbb Z$ by $1$. It is not always true that a f.g. $\mathbb Z$-module has a submodule isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, $T$ need not contain (a copy of) the $R$-module $R$, nor does $T$ have to be contained in (a copy of) the $R$ module $R$.

You could take, for example, the $\Bbb Z$ module $M=\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$. It does not contain a copy of $\Bbb Z$ because, well, it is finite, and couldn't possibly contain the infinite set $\Bbb Z$.

Secondly $M$ can't be isomorphic to a submodule of $\Bbb Z$ because all the submodules of $\Bbb Z$ look like $n\Bbb Z$ for some integer $n$, and these are all infinite except for the zero ideal.

Given a finitely generated $R$ module $M$ generated by $n$ elements, the best you can say in general is that $M$ is isomorphic to a quotient of the free module $R^n$.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, don't have enough Rep points to comment, but I agree with Ferra, this is a nonsense question, as by definition, an $R$-module $A$ is defined to be a function from $R\times A \to A$, so it makes no sense to ask if $R\subset T$.

As an example, remember any abelian group is automatically a $\mathbb{Z}$-module, hence if $G$ is some abelian group, and $g\in G$, then 3$g$ = $g+g+g$, so I can't see how you can make the connection that $\mathbb{Z}\subset G$.

Now let $G$ be the group of polynomial functions, and let $S\subset G$ be all the polynomials with no constant term. Then this submodule is all polynomials, and their are no constants, so.....

I'm going to bed here, but just to be completely explicit, let your group be $\mathbb{Z}[X]$ under addition, and $S$ be as above, then as a $2\mathbb{Z}$-submodule, you can see S isn't contained in... and vice versa.

I agree with Ferra Stucky. I certainly had fun thinking about it too, but as Ferra said, apriori and all. Pedals and wheels are required for a bike to move, but this doesn't mean they are the same thing.